# What is the difference between Total,User & Privileged ProcessTime?

Tags: c#, .net, process, cpu

I want to measure the time taken by a code on the cpu. (cpu time)
But i don't know which one i have to use TotalProcessTime or UserProcessTime ?

And Can someone explain to me what is the difference between them (3 Process Time) using example ? (in msdn is not very clear).

Comment: Whenever a program in a operating system executes, there's both time spent by the user code, and time spent by the OS code.

Comment: so i need to use the total time or usertime to have the good accurate time ?

Comment: the user code is the code programm and what is the os code ?!!

Answer (score 2):

In most Linux and Windows like operating systems, a given program can execute in two modes: kernel/system or user.

In very simple terms:

- Kernel mode: in this mode, code running in the program can access all memory, hardware etc on the host computer. As this unrestricted access means that mistakes can cause serious system crashes, running in this mode is usually restricted to very well tested system level code, accessed from the user level code via system API calls.
- User mode: In this mode the code running in the program does not have low level access to hardware, kernel space memory etc. Code running in this mode must call system API's to perform these tasks. When the system API is invoked the mode changes and the program enters Kernel mode as above.

For more info on Windows user vs kernel mode see - look at the top comment also which provides some extra insight:

- http://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-user-and-kernel-mode/

More general Unix user vs Kernal mode, this slideshare is a nice resource:

- http://www.slideshare.net/siddiqueibrahim37/kernel-mode-vs-user-mode-in-linux

To answer your original question: kernel mode is also referred to as priviliged mode sometimes. A program will spend some time in user mode and some time in kernel mode when it is executing (as a general rule it will spend most  of its time in user mode). The time spent in each mode is the user and privileged times in your question and the total time is the sum of the two times.

Note that not all computer architectures use this two mode approach.